# Efficiently iterating a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

So here's the problem, I'm importing a dictionary with anywhere from 6000 to 12000 keys. Then using a nested for algorithm to group them into a list inside of another dictionary. I'm using the following code to check if the key is in the dictionary:

```
for key in range(sizeOfOriginalKeys):
    if key in key_data:
```

As you might imagine, this is taking forever since the sorting algorithm is fairly complex. I would like to only iterate through the keys in 'key_data', without doing 1000 to 11999 checks if there is that key in the dictionary. Is there a way to make a list of current keys? Then iterate through them? Or at least something more efficient than what I'm currently doing?

Current Code after Kevin's suggestion:

```
for key in key_data:
    currentKey = key_data[key].name
    if key_data[currentKey].prefList[currentPref] == currentGroup
        key_data[currentKey].currentScore = getDotProduct()
        group_data[currentGroup].keyList.append(key_data[currentKey])
        group_data[currentGroup].sortKeys()
        del key_data[currentKey]
```

The key names are integers.
At the end of the sorting algorithm I delete the key, if its been sorted into a group.
Now I get an error: dictionary changed size during iteration.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you show a bit more of your algorithm's skeleton?

Comment: Sure, one moment. I'll edit my original post.

Comment: key checking in a dict is an O(1) operation, so very cheap - perhaps there are other areas that need to be optimised. Don't delete the item from key_data in the loop, you can't change the dict you are operating over. If you need to know you've handled it then add the key to a handled `set()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying too hard:

```
for key in key_data:
```

Comment: I could literally kiss you! For legal reasons, I won't.

Comment: Wait, I just ran the code. So, at the end of the algorithm it deletes the key out of the dictionary. Which throws the error: dictionary changed size during iteration. Any way around that?

Comment: @TheNoviceAllen There's no easy way around that - unless you can delay the deletion. If you can, just put the keys you want to delete into a list, and delete everything after the `for`

Comment: @TheNoviceAllen: Alternatively, do `for key in list(key_data)`.

Comment: I created a temp dictionary to handle people getting removed. Though maybe I should try the list, it seems more efficient. I might do that later, right now I'm dealing with a problem where all of the keys aren't getting assigned to a group. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
for key,value in key_data.items() :
    print key
    print value
```

you can access to value without calling key_data[key]

Comment: did you forget `.items()`? or possibly `iteritems()`?

Comment: opps! sorry about that