# Iterating over dictionary efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program is taking input from stdin (from the user) and based on the input calling a function.

```
 dict = {'cd': cd} #etc
 cmd = input('enter command: ')
```

for instance one function may be a function to change the directory:

```
def cd(dir):
    os.Chdir(dir)
```

This function would require a additional parameter to work correctly.

In order to pass the additional argument I am using a for loop that utilizes string slicing and the dict function to retrieve the function (for i in the range of smallest key to largest key):

```
for i in range(1, len(max(dict.keys(), key=len))):
     target = dict.get(cmd[:i+1])
     if target:
         target(cmd)
```

This for loop should call the 'cd()' function if cmd is equal to 'çd '..

I'm curious if it is more efficient to use a for loop to iterate over the dict keys or is using the '.get()' function the fastest and most efficient method or is there a better method for checking user input efficiently?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiently iterating a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414272/efficiently-iterating-a-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: Your second example is kind of confusing. Can you edit your question to provide a concrete example of what you expect `dict` to be in that second example, and what you expect `cmd` to be, and what you expect to happen?

Comment: It does not answer because it involves slicing also, the answers don't answer if .get() or iterating over the dict is more efficient.

Comment: @AlfredRelory `.get` is more efficient, but your questions is totally unclear to me. What exactly are you doing here? Can you give concrete, runnable examples? I have no idea why you are iterating over `range(1, len(max(dict.keys(), key=len)))`, it doesn't seem necessary at all. What is that loop supposed to achieve?

Comment: Why are you even *considering* iterating over the dictionary?  There is exactly one item of interest in the dictionary (the one corresponding to the command the user typed), you should retrieve that item directly.

Comment: I cannot retreive that item correctly because what if the command is 'cd home' or 'cd /' there's no way to predict the command's parameters that are going to passed to the cd() function